# Book recommendations for learning how to fly?

Tags: flight-training, books, literature-recommendation

With the success of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6348/good-book-to-learn-basic-aerodynamics-in-plane-design/6371#6371), which asks about good books on aerodynamics, I thought I'd ask another general question regarding books that we can turn into a community wiki.

What are good books to use to learn how to fly?  And yes, I know that, in the end, you'll just need a good instructor.  But there are several books that suppliment a good instructor, or can be used by people who are interested in learning to fly, but perhaps are unable to get an instructor just yet.

**Note:** I am well aware this is a very general question.  But I would like to have a centralized resource, vetted by users of this stack, that we can point to when someone asks for text resources on learning how to fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you pointed out in your question, no book is a substitute for actual instruction in an aircraft with a flight instructor. That being said, doing your homework and knowing what your instructor is going to expect goes a long way toward completing your training in a timely manner.
The books here are all great reference texts to be combined with a flight instruction curriculum.

### FAA Publications / Books for initial training

A surprising number of new student pilots are not aware of the wealth of information the FAA has compiled and published to help people learn to fly. There is a whole series of [FAA Handbooks and Manuals](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/) that you can take advantage of which are available from the FAA as well as from a variety of publishers like [ASA](http://www.asa2fly.com). While all of the regulatory information is geared toward US/FAA regulations much of the technique information, signs & markings, etc. will be universal, in conformance with ICAO rules.
I list a whole bunch of them here, but you can find a wealth of information by googling what you want to do and the words "FAA Handbook".

1. **Books on Flying the aircraft** - maneuvers, etc.
   Quite simply if it flies the FAA probably has a book about how you should fly it.  These books cover basic flying technique and the maneuvers the FAA expects pilots to be able to demonstrate.
   The popular ones include:
   [The Airplane Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/airplane_handbook/) (FAA-H-8083-3A)
   [The Helicopter Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/helicopter_flying_handbook/) (FAA-H-8083-21A)
   [The Glider Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/glider_handbook/) (FAA-H-8083-13A)
   [The Balloon Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/media/FAA-H-8083-11.pdf) (FAA-H-8083-11A)
2. **Books on "essential aviation knowledge"** - Airport signs & markings, "rules of the air", etc.
   [The Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/) (FAA-H-8083-25A) is the starting point here.
   [The Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM)](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/AIM/Index.htm) is another key resource (you will often find this as a combined "FAR/AIM" printed publication).
3. **Books for the more advanced stuff** - Instrument ratings and beyond
   [The Instrument Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/FAA-H-8083-15B.pdf) (FAA-H-8083-15B) and [Instrument Procedures Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/) (FAA-H-8083-16) are excellent references for pilots pursuing an instrument rating.

Comment: +1, Very comprehensive answer, Well Done.