# Where can I find the best site to learn aircraft design on a small scale?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, model-aircraft

I am undergraduate student still trying to figure out a lot about Aerodynamics and aircraft design. I am learning how to design rc planes.

So the thing I know the weight of my plane which is between 700 gm to 1000 gm and velocity which is 13 m/s.

I just know the basics that is the lift formula and other fundamentals. I want to know how to design a nice fuselage for my plane and also how to keep balance in my plane. I seriously need help and also there are courses where you learn all this, but they ask for heavy cash.

Comment: Hi Sai. I will let the community decide on this, but I have to warn you that this question is a bit borderline for us, as it asks to locate external resources (leaving aside that "best" is opinion-based) and generally these questions are not accepted here.
Please take a moment to go through these help pages:
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Are you open to learning from paper books as opposed to web sites?  There are a number of very good books on aerodynamic design oriented toward model size aircraft, typically sold through hobby supply outlets.

Comment: Yes !...I am to books too!

Comment: As Federico explained, this question is a bit borderline on 3 areas: asking for external resources (off topic), asking for best resource (opinion-based), asking for RC planes (most of us fly real planes here, although aerodynamics still applies). I hesitated for a few minutes but ultimately decided to vote to close. I hope the existing answers, as well as [this related question here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6348/3386), covers what you need.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a website, but it's totally worth buying: Dan Raymer's *Simplified Aircraft Design for Homebuilders* (ISBN 10: 0972239707  ISBN 13: 9780972239707) is applicable to RC aircraft and has the best ratio of comprehensive coverage to beginner-friendliness of any resource I know.

Answer (score -1):

13 meters per second calculates out to around 30 mph.
At 1 kilogram, you should have no problem whatsoever
getting it in the air.  Models at this weight generally land at around 8 to 15 mph and are capable of around 50+ mph at full throttle.  I would start by looking at classic airplane designs like the Piper Cub.

One of the best sources of more info would be your
local hobby shop.

Bob